# Does Orderer have Block(Ledger) data?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I built hyperledger fabric network using Kafka-based Ordering Service.

I thought that Orderer doesn't have Block data.
But, when I checked /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains/mychannel in Orderer server, I found blockfile_000000 file.
I checked this file using "less" command.
Then, I found key-value data which I registered by invoking chaincode.

What is this file?
This means that Orderer also maintain Block data(i.e. Ledger)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The orderer has the blockchain of all channels it is part of.

However, it doesn't have the world state and it doesn't inspect the content of the transactions.

It just writes the blocks into the disk, to serve peers that pull the blocks from it.

Comment: So, the orderer should have same size of storage to keep blocks as peer has ? Does it grow without limit ?

Comment: Thank you for clarification !

Comment: Hey I am using raft ordering service and it seems orderers are consuming a lot of disk space although the transactions are not that much. Can you let me know why is this happening?